# CSS border radius does not work in Windows sidebar gadget

Tags: html, css, widget

I am trying to design a Windows sidebar gadget and I want to include a circle that will be filled red or green. The code below creates a circle when I run it in a browser such as IE or chrome, but when I open the widget, it is a square. Do gadgets not support border-radius? Anyway around this without using an image?

```
   <div id = "circle></div>
    #circle {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
      -moz-border-radius: 25px;
      border-radius: 25px;
      background: red;
    }
```

Comment: hmm.. border-radius does not work for IE8 and below, I suppose the Widgets run on an old Trident engine then? try using the [CSS Pie](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-border-radius-in-internet-explorer/)

Comment: @Aziz I tried this and it still does not work but thanks for the suggestion!